# Cakephp SUM of related field

Tags: php, cakephp-1.2

I'm fairly new to cakephp, I need to find the SUM of a one-to-many related table inside a cakephp query.

I have table Users
and table Invoices

I want a total sum of the Invoices that belong to the user when I do a find on the Users table. The result I'm looking for is to show users and aggregate totals of invoices.

I've searched and it looks like cakephp 1.3 has a feature called virtualfields, but the app I'm working on is cake 1.2... I'm not sure I want to chance an upgrade of the framework to 1.3.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your find (make the appropriate changes):

```
array('fields' => array('sum(Model.quantity) AS total')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works if I put a subquery in the fields list:
`array('fields' => array('(SELECT SUM(Invoice.total) FROM Invoices WHERE Users.id = User.id) as total)')`
The problem is it also wipes out all of the other fields that get selected.  Is there a way to preserve those?

Comment: Did you try array('fields' => array('(SELECT SUM(Invoice.total) FROM Invoices WHERE Users.id = User.id) as total)','Field1', 'Field2') ?

Comment: Don't forget sum is an aggregator so you may need to use "group by".

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Looks ugly... Especially since cake is supposed to abstract the sql, but it works.  The cake 1.3 solution is much more elegant.